# Specifying proxy for cxf-codegen-plugin

Tags: maven, cxf-codegen-plugin

How do you specify a proxy that needs to be used by cxf-codegen-plugin. I tried specifying proxy in the maven settings.xml, but that was not picked up.

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.0.0

Comment: Then this post should help you: http://www.wolfe.id.au/2011/05/26/using-apache-cxf-and-maven-with-a-proxy-server/

Comment: I added cxf.xml in src/main/resources with http conduit details as advised, but cxf-codegen-plugin did not seem to pick up that file. I ended up using SoapUI to fetch the complete wsdl and adding that to the project.

Comment: Can you add all configurations? (repository.xml, pom.xml... etc). Have you a proxy in your net?

Answer (score 1):

maven settings.xml in ~/.m2 folder works just fine for me for cxf-codegen-plugin. Example:

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>myproxy</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>proxy.example.com</host>
        <port>8080</port>
        <username><!-- username --></username>
        <password><!-- pass --></password>
        <nonProxyHosts>*.local|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
  </proxy>
</proxies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried:

```
mvn -Dhttp.proxyHost=[_] -Dhttp.proxyPort=[_] clean package

([_] -> Your proxy data)
```

On console and worked.